# Finding two possible basis in $\mathbb{C}^2$ given a change of basis matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

For an exercise I am trying to solve, I am presented with a matrix, P:
$$P = \begin{pmatrix} 
1-i & 2 \\
1+i & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$$

And I must find two possible bases in $\mathbb{C}^2$ so that $P$ is one of the matrices that result in a change of basis. My reasoning has been that one can suppose that one of the bases, $B'$, is $\{(1,0),(0,i)\}$, and therefore one can argue that the columns in $P$ are the coordinates of the vectors in other such base, $B$, expressed in terms of the basis vectors in $B'$. Therefore it's possible to calculate:
$$(1-i)(1,0) + (1+i)(0,i) = (1-i,-1+i)$$
$$2(1,0)+1(0,i)=(2,i)$$

And then $B=\{ (1-i,-1+i), (2,i)\}$ and P would be the matrix used to change from $B$ to $B'$.

But I am not really sure about my solution. Am I right in making up one of the bases so that the operations are simpler? Is there a better way to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won’t be able to arbitrarily choose one of the bases because the change-of-basis matrix is uniquely defined.

Let’s say the two bases are A and B. Since P is a change of basis matrix, it takes a vector represented in one basis and sends it into the other basis.

$$
P:[v]_{A}\to[v]_{B}
$$

The columns of P are exactly the basis vectors of A represented in the basis B.

$$
P=([A_{1}]_{B},[A_{2}]_{B})
$$

Note that the inverse of P reverses this process.

$$
P^{-1}:[v]_{B}\to[v]_{A}
$$

Thus to find $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$,

$$
\begin{align}
[A_{1}]_{A}&=P^{-1}[A_{1}]_{B}\\
[A_{2}]_{A}&=P^{-1}[A_{2}]_{B}
\end{align}
$$

The B basis can be found similarly.

Comment: Thank you very much! This really made it clear, you've been a great help.